# Differentiating Fourier series where $f(-L) \ne f(L)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In a previous question on this forum I described my issues on using the assumption of the solution being in the form of a Fourier series to solve the following differential equation.

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} = f(x) \qquad f(x) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[A_0\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) + B_0\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right] $$

Upon term-by-term differentiation the assumed form $f(x)$ and substituting into the original equation a trivial solution yielded. This was explained to be that the term-by-term differentiation is essentially imposing a boundary condition that $f(L) = f(-L)$.

My question is that is there a way to find derivatives of Fourier series such that $f(-L) \ne f(L)$, I understand that the derivative of such a Fourier series will be undefined at $x = (2n+1)L$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, but can an expression be defined for the derivative of the Fourier series in-between such values.

Comment: Could you please add the details on what solution you get? How did you get non-zero coefficients from this DE?

Comment: I asked about it here, essentially I get contradictory results for the relationship between B_n and A_n, such that it can only be satisfied if both A_n = 0 and B_n = 0.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388854/contradictory-results-from-using-orthogonality-when-solving-an-ode-with-fourier

Comment: Yes...because that is the only periodic solution to the ODE. There's no working around that.